# How do I put a boolean into a list and output it in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, boolean

So I am new to Haskell and below I have attempted to program a function that takes a given value of e and a given list and determines whether that given value appears in the list given outputting True if the value given does appear and False if not.

```
inListm e [] = False 
inListm e (x:xs)
 | e == x = True || inListm e xs
 | otherwise = False || inListm e xs
```

If

```
inListm 2 [0, 2, 1, 2]
```

is given, the output would be

```
True
```

However, I would like the final output to be in a list like this

```
[True]
```

I have attempted to do this by

```
inListd e [] =  False : []
inListd e (x:xs)
  | e == x = True : [] || inListd e xs
  | otherwise = False :[]  || inListd e xs
```

but all that gives me is an error so I would like to know how I could resolve this

Comment: Well, `True || <whatever>` is `True`, and `False || <whatever>` is `<whatever>`. So one first step would be to eliminate the `||`s, as in `| e == x = True | otherwise = inListm e xs`. Then your idea of just tossing a `:[]` in as appropriate works, producing `| e == x = True : [] | otherwise = inListm e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. The only thing necessary is to return a list if you have a result, so:

```
inListd :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Bool]
inListd e [] = [False] 
inListd e (x:xs)
 | e == x = [True]
 | otherwise = inListd e xs
```

That being said, I does not seem to make much sense to wrap the result in a list.

Answer (score 4):

Consider reusing your existing function; reuse is a big part of what makes writing big programs possible. Like this:

```
inListd e xs = inListm e xs : []
-- OR
inListd e xs = [inListm e xs]
```